# How to put a crossreference in Rbookdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I am not sure I understand this part from the [documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/tables.html#tables)

> the table label for a code chunk with the label foo will be tab:foo

Say I have a RMarkdown chunck such as

````
```{r mytable, echo=FALSE}
kable(df, booktabs=T)
```
````

I would consider `mytabel` as the label for the code chunck. That means I should be able to type a narrative that looks like:

This is my table \@ref(tab:mytable)

And the \@ref should reference the table number instead of the chucnk id. Instead I get a double (and clickable) `??` .What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second paragraph of the [documention](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/tables.html):

> Like figures, tables with captions will also be numbered and can be referenced.

So you want to cross-reference a table, you must specify the `caption` argument.

You can create a empty RStudio project and  or save following code as `index.Rmd` file. Or download
 https://github.com/yihui/bookdown-minimal and replace the content of `index.Rmd` file with the following code. Then you can press `Build Book` button in the `Build` panel.

````
---
title: "A Book"
author: "Frida Gomam"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output:
  bookdown::gitbook: default
---

# reference

This is my table \@ref(tab:mytable)

# table

```{r mytable, echo=TRUE}
knitr::kable(iris[1:10, ], booktabs=T, caption='A table of the first 10 rows of the mtcars data')
```
````

Comment: Thanks, I still get the double question mark. Also, could you post the output? And what if the caption is longer like 'this is my table'? In these examples https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/tables.html#tab:table-single the code that is echoed doesn't refer to the caption.